# Ruby Fixnum Division Not Calculating As Expected

Tags: ruby

In irb, the result of -3/4 is -1, not 0. However, the result of 3/4 is 0, as expected.

Does anyone know what happened?

Thank you!

I get the floor idea, thank you!

Comment: What do you expect? Also, explain your logic of why you expect that.

Comment: I was expecting - 3 / 4 result in 0. because / has higher priority, 3/4 is 0. then calculate -0 => 0.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html

Comment: `-` is not prioritized as a mathematical operation but a unary one in the example. It is a identifier of the disposition to the left of zero. e.g. this is not interpreted as `-(3/4)` but rather `(-3)/4`

Comment: even though - is a unary operator, how come 0-3/4 is 0 while -3/4 is -1? Just curious and I am very confused....

Comment: @BugsBunny in the second case `-` is a mathematical operation `0-(3/4)` as determined by `Fixnum#-` or now `Integer#-` *"Performs subtraction: the class of the resulting object depends on the class of numeric."* as read from left to right where as the first case is unary `Integer#@-` *"Returns int, negated."* as mentioned below in the answer the result will be "floored" causing `0.75` to floor to `0` and `0.75` round to `-1`. simple test `0.75.floor #=> 0` and `-0.75.floor #=> -1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happen because the [/ operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-2F) performs the `floor` operation.

So `-3/4` is equal to -1 and not zero. And `3/4` is equal to zero and not 1.

[fix_div](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/numeric.c#L3720) is the method ruby uses to do the division. And `fix_div` uses [fix_divide](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/numeric.c#L3686), and [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/numeric.c#L3707) you can see where the `floor` method is called.

The `fix_div` and `fix_divide` are C methods.

Comment: That's good to know. The doc [Integer#/](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Integer.html#method-i-2F) states, "Performs division: the class of the resulting object depends on the class of numeric.", which I don't find especially helpful.

Comment: @CarySwoveland [Newer documentation](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/Integer.html#method-i-2F) is better, now says *"Performs division; for integer numeric, truncates the result to an integer"*.